# Blank screen when setting console resolution on Ubuntu 10.04 Server

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, vmware-workstation

I've tried 3 different systems including VMWare with very same Ubuntu 10.04 (Server Edition) basic installation.

- Phisical computer
- VirtualBox
- VMWare

On first two, I am able to easily change console resolution(not grub resolution) by altering /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

Then of course sudo update-grub2; sudo reboot

However, with VMWare, `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep` will result to blank screen (although based on windows size seems like resolution is set after bootup).

I've tried on 7.x and 8.0.2 versions of VMWare Workstation. So the question is, what special steps to be done in order to change console resolution on VMWare?

Answer (score 1):

Since these GRUB settings work with BIOS video modes, chances are that the VMware BIOS (a heavily modified Phoenix BIOS) does not support what you are asking it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Does the VMWare Community entry [Workstation 11 + Debian 8 = GRUB gfxpayload problem & blank screen](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/514376) help you?

Quoting the accepted answer there:

> Try appending `vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=1` to the kernel command-line and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Please note that this is a 3 year old question. You're unlikely to get a response from the original poster of the question.

Comment: I had noticed that ... I found the link while fixing a similar problem (blank screen when setting console resolution in VMWare), and it helped me. So maybe this can still save someone else Google'ing this issue some time -- even if OP has long since moved on.